# Create a view which is visible over all applications

Tags: android

I want to create a view which is always visible even when my application is not in foreground(Like Toast). And also I can hide this view when task completed.
For Example: Like the view of CPU usage in android 4.0 which is visible on all screens in top left corner of device

Comment: why don't you use a toast?

Comment: because I cant set timeout for toast.

Comment: yes, and you can keep it displayed for as long as you need, as long as you call show() once in a while.

Comment: But I think StandOut library is good way to achieve this.

Comment: StandOut library seems like a good solution but another way you can do this, and with more control, is to use a `Service`. You then can set the view of the `Service`. I assume that's how the StandOut library works. That is how Facebook creates their ChatHeads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) library, it enables you to create applications that can hover on top of the other apps on the screen.

Once you get it imported to your project you just create a class that extends `StandOutWindow` override all of the relavent methods and then to show it you call like this:

```
StandOutWindow.show(this, YourWindow.class, StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);
```

The library takes care of the rest for you, and even enables your windows to be shown/hidden from the view itself or the notification bar.